# Regex code for insert word between two words and non-alpha numeric

Tags: regex, perl

Let's say I have a sentence comprise of two words and some punctuation/number.

For example

word1 [some Punctuation/number] word2

I want to insert word3 between them before the punctuation.
So the output will be

word1 word3 [some Punctuation/number] word2

What is the proper regex code to do that? Preferably written in Perl.

Comment: well I try to use this
`$a = word1 word2`

`$b = word1 word3 word2`

`$line =~ s/$a/$b/i`

But it will fail in case there is some number/punctuation between word1 and word2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = 'word1 , word2';
my $re = qr/(\w+) ([\p{P}\d])/;
$string =~ s/$re/$1 word3 $2/;
print $string,"\n";
```

**Output:**

```
word1 word3 , word2
```

*Edit:*

If the punctuation is optional, use this:

```
my $re = qr/(\w+) ([\p{P}\d]?)/;
#                    here __^
```

Comment: Thanks for the script! But will it work in case there are nothing but spaces between word1 and word2?

Comment: @IllSc: you can make the punctuation optional, see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=\s)(\p{P}|\d+)(?=\s)
```

Try this.See demo.Replace by `word3 $1`

https://regex101.com/r/eZ0yP4/22

Comment: Do you know how do I directly apply this to Perl?
I'm not very good at regex especially backreference regex

Comment: @IllSc `    $re = "/(?<=\\s)(\\p{P}|\\d+)(?=\\s)/";`
  `  $str = "word1 , word2";`
  `  $subst = "word3 $1";`
     
    $result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);`